# How to call a MainWindow method from another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to call a method from the MainWindow in another window.
Problem is i don't know why i got an error and i would like to fix it.

I tried to call the fonction using various ways, none of them worked.
Here is my last try :

What i want to call :

```cs
namespace Class1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ...
        public void SkipVideo()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how i tried to call :

```cs
namespace Class1
{
    public partial class TimeWindow : Window
    {
        ...
        private void DemoVideo_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).SkipVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

There is no build error, but when i run the program, it does this :
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Class1.TimeWindow' to type 'Class1.MainWindow'.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvalidCastException` means that your application's mainwindow is a `TimeWindow`.

Provided that there actually is a `MainWindow` open, you can get a reference to it like this:

```
private void DemoVideo_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (mainWindow != null)
        mainWindow.SkipVideo();
}
```

There are better ways to handle this, for example using the MVVM design pattern as suggested by @Christopher, but this is probably the easiest one given your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeWindow` instance needs to be handed a reference to `mainWindow` instance, to call `mainWindow.SkipVideo()`. Usually the place for this is when you create `TimeWindow` in `mainWindow`. A public property or Cosntructor Argument in TimeWindow can be used to hand in the instance.

*However* you are using WPF and this is a Windows Forms Programming approach. WPF/UWP was designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. This is not the MVVM pattern. While you can use older approaches, doing so misses about 90% of the power of WPF and runs into issues at every other corner. If you plan on working in WPF, you definitely need to learn MVVM. MVVM includes a way to share data/functions across Windows like this.

A few years ago I did write a introduction into MVVM: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf However I have to admit that my understanding of how to play video from the ViewModel with manipulation options is a bit beyond me, so pure MVVM might not be a good idea in this case. Or a Prefabricated Control might be better.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, and try to code my future projects with this. But on this program, it's a bit too late to restart almost everything ahah. Anyways, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

-Just you should to do this code in MainWindow Class :

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
            public static MainWindow _instance;
            public MainWindow()
            {
                _instance = this;
                InitializeComponent();
            }
private void SkipVideo()
{

}
    }
```

-And now you can call any method,user control,..etc:

```
public partial class TimeWindow : Window
{
    ...
    private void DemoVideo_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow._instance.SkipVideo();
    }
}
```